# The build agent creates workspaces owner asThe Project Collection Build Service

Tags: tfsbuild

we have created user account in the tfsbuild agent as 'tfsuser'. But when i run the build, i see the workspace created with the owner as 'Team Foundation Build Service'.

How to make the workspace owner as logged on user which is here tfsuser.

This is creating issues being default user 'tfsuser' vs 'Team Foundation Build Service' being different.

Any suggestions please!!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What issues is this causing?

Comment: I want to change the owner  to custom user (unique user id created to log in to the server) instead of team foundation build service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the expected behavior.

The "`Project Collection Build Service`" is the "`built-in` build service identity.
When you building with agent, it need a workspace. This workspace which owner is `Project Collection Build Service` is created during the building.

However you can change the owner of the workspace following below steps:

From Team Explorer, **Manage Workspaces** -->  Select the workspace then **Edit** --> Select **Advanced** -->
In the Advanced Edit Workspace Window, you will find option for Owner. You can update there  --> Then **OK**.

[image]

Comment: Yes this is the exact option that i did. Thought there could be another approach by updating the default Build Service user. Thank  you and this is a work around helped me for now.